# How to modify field code to include sub-sub-sections and text in the text body?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, cross-reference, field-codes

Is there a way to cross-reference a section, chapter or heading in word with more than one sub section, e.g., Section 3.4.4.2?

I figured out how to include text within the hyperlink with this code (including one subsection number):

```
{REF _Ref128198017 \r \h \# "Section 0.0" \* Charformat}
```

but I can't figure out how to put all subsections (multiple numbers) within the same field code without using multiple field codes, e.g.:

```
{REF _Ref128198017 \r \h \# "Section " \* Charformat}{REF _Ref128198017 \r \h \* Charformat}
```

Is there a way to maybe add static text infront of the heading number within the field code?

PS: I've tried all combinations of 0.0, 0;0, 0.x.x, #.#.#, etc.

Comment: AFAICS you cannot reduce the field count, but an alternative that might have some advantages would be to nest the numeric part within the first numeric switch (as long s you aren't using single quotation marks in your numbering), e.g. {REF _Ref128198017 \\r \\h \\# "Section '{REF _Ref128198017 \\r}'" \\*Charformat}

Comment: @jonsson This gives me the result I wanted. Thank you. It's going to be a bit cumbersome to apply to the whole document though. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose I'd try to write a little bit of VBA to help, but if you're not in a position to do that it could certainly be a slog. BTW there should only be one backslash before the r, h and hash options as I am sure you realised -

Answer (score 0):

### There is nothing built into Word that does this.

The best workaround would be two cross-references, to the first and last heading.

Instead, you could add a bookmark that encompasses all of the material and insert a hyperlink to that with your own descriptive text. The link, though, would just take the user to the starting point. The same point you would get with a cross-reference to the first heading.